custom item field not available for custom pdf layout
I'm trying to add the contents of a custom field we created in Netsuite to a custom invoice PDF printout.  I've done this before and it's pretty easy, but this time when I try to add the custom field, it isn't available for the custom PDF layout.  The custom field is of the type item and I'm trying to add it to the columns of the PDF invoice layout, but when I go into 'Printing Fields' while editing the custom transaction form, the field isn't available there. I suspect I have to do something to the item field to make it available on a transaction, but I have no idea what that something is.  Any kick in the pants would be greatly appreciated.

Generally you have to also create a custom column field that is sourced from the custom item field.
It can be hidden so as not to clutter your form layouts.
For freemarker templates it does not have to be stored. Whether you need it always current or only current at the time the item was specified on the transaction dictates that.

Thank you.  I didn't even think about it like this.  I just assumed I'd be able to pull it from the item record like a join in SQL.
